# Debugging Sencha Fiddle?

Tags: extjs

It does not seem possible to debug Sencha Fiddles which is a shame.

There doesn't seem to be anything presented in the debugger which allows me to put breakpoints in my code.

[image]

I looked at both : Firefox 38 and Internet Explorer 11, but the source files look the same.

I also tried adding 'debugger;' statements in code but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas if it is possible?

Comment: Put a `debugger;` in your code.

Comment: tried that it doesnt work. It stops somewhere... the step over buttons and play buttons appear, but there is just an empty text file as it seems.

Comment: Yea it seems it doesn't work so well in FireFox. It does work in Chrome, so I'd recommend using that.

Comment: not allowed to. Company I am working for only allow us to use shitty browsers. Would love to use Chrome.

Comment: Ah, that's a pain! Perhaps creating a test Sencha application somewhere locally and using that as your playground would be the best way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that if I look at the sources, and then under fiddle-run-iframe, i can fine my app.js object which is where my code is kept :

[image]